# what is the best way to check session in codiginator everytime make a new request

Tags: php, mysql

i know how to use session in codiginator but i am facing the problem with session management and little bit confuse ie how can i check every time a valid session in controller.

i do this by using

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {

function __construct() {
                        parent::__construct();
                        $this->load->helper('url');
                        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
                        $this->load->library('form_validation');
                        $this->load->library('session');
                        $this->load->model('User');
                        $this->load->model('Enquiry_model');
        }
    public function index()
            {
                    //$data['status']=$this->Blog_model->status();
                    $data['main_product']=$this->Enquiry_model->getMainProduct();
                    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                    if(!$session_data)
                    {
                            $this->welcome();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data['user_data'] = $session_data;
                        $this->load->view('admin1/index1',$data);
                    }


            }

}
?>
```

but facing the problem when i have two website and i use same table to check the user but the different database for both. the problem i am facing when i logedin to first website i automatically logged in to other one. how can i remove or solve this problem.